# Grepping one column of a CSV file using a very large input CSV file

Tags: bash, python, csv

I have a folder 300Gb in size containing large (around 2GB) *CSV* files. My job is to extract particular rows from those files that have a value in a particular column that also exists in an input file I have (also 2GB in size).

I am currently trying to use a `python` based approach using *Pandas* to obtain the data I want but this process is very slow and due to limitations, I have have to read both the input file and each file in the folder in as chunks, which is taking quite a while to do:

```
all_wow_files = glob.glob('/media/noname365/0205D5FE310DDEEC/bing_verticals_wow_job/US_WOW/*_Keywords.csv')

for file in all_wow_files:

    print(file)

    for chunk in pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=500000):

            for chunk_dupe in pd.read_csv('input_file.csv',chunksize=500000, names=['Keyword']):

                keyword_list = set(chunk_dupe['Keyword'].tolist())

                chunk = chunk[chunk['Keyword'].isin(keyword_list)]

                chunk.to_csv(output_file,index=False, mode='a')
```

Is there a particular command in `bash` I could use to get the job done faster? I really don't want to read the entire input file into memory for comparison's sake...

**EDIT:**

The files in the folder are generally built like this, in my output I need all of the columns included:

```
Parent ID, ID, Keyword 
1            1  yodel
1            2  keyworks
1            3  puppy dog
2            4  see-saw
...........
```

while the input file I am using is just one-column of string's:

```
apple
banana
orange
see-saw
moneybags
.....
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of the input data and an example of the desired  output.

Answer (score 2):

This awk script can do the the work (and will not load the entire file in memory)

```
awk -F\; '/Keyword/' input.csv >output.csv
```

Supposing delimiter is `;`, keyword is `Keyword`, the input file is `input.csv` and the output file is `output.csv`

If you want to search for particular column to contain the keyword you should use something like:

```
awk -F\; '$5==Keyword' input.csv >output.csv
```

or

```
awk -F\; '$5==Keyword {print}' input.csv >output.csv
```

To search for more than one keyword you can use something like:

```
awk -F\; '$5==Keyword1 || $6==Keyword2 {print}' input.csv >output.csv
```

Comment: I'll give this a try! Is it possible to apply this to all files in the directory in a loop but have the output file name the extracted keywords are put in be similar to the input files name? This is probably a separate question in of itself.

Comment: Hang on, jut re-read your answer. The input.csv file actually contains all of the keywords I have to find IN the 300GB folder. I cannot search for one keyword at a time here as I have several million to search for matches for.

Comment: See my edited answer

Comment: @user260504 If you want to loop and change the output filename: `for f in files; do some_command "$f" > "${f%.*}-modified.csv"; done` or similar. See [String Manipulation](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for more info.

Comment: @slhck, thanks for that. That's two keywords down only several million more to go! lol